# MongoDB - Update array of nested objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I have a MongoDB document with this structure which I'm creating/updating through a REST service in NestJS.

Here, incidentNumber is the primary key.

```
{
  "incidentNumber": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "resource": [
    "string"
  ],
  "actionsItems": {
    "detection": [
      {
        "key": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ],
    "prevention": [
      {
        "key": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My concern is about updating **actionItems** object. It is an array of objects.
Whenever I use `findByIdAndUpdate,` it does not update the individual object inside it if there is any intended change.

UI will send the entire object, which will have only a few properties different than the previous version in the database.

The existing code to update the document:

```
await this.incidentModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      incidentNumber,
      updateIncidentDTO,
      { new: true },
    );
```

How can I tackle this situation? Kindly assist. TIA.

Comment: why dont you use updateOne function ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Would you mind sharing the query in the above context?

Comment: sure but something is weird, i guess that you need to have the same property name ID on parent, child and nested objects. Im asking bc given your UI explanation you will need to be able to update either the parent and/or nested object/s, am i correct ?

Comment: Maybe I put it the wrong way. UI will send the entire object which will have only few properties different than the previous version in the database.

Comment: Can you share the payload coming from the UI?